# Firing an event only once after input change

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have a live search function that fires an event every time text_input changes using `text_input.addEventListener('input', ...)`. How do I go about firing the event only once after like every 5 seconds of no change because right now even with setTimeOut, it fires the event equal to that of the number of changes made in text_input, it would look like this.

```
// listen for changes in text_input
text_input.addEventListener('input', function(){

  // execute code here only once every 5 seconds of no change in text_input

})
```

Comment: Look up "js event debouncing"

Comment: use debouncer pattern, if you need to learn it, you can come here: https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/javascript-throttle-and-debounce-patterns/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

```
function debounceFunction(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;

  return function executedFunction() {
    var context = this;
    var args = arguments;
        
    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };

    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};

var returnedFunction = debounceFunction(function() {
    // The function's code
}, 250);

text_input.addEventListener('input', returnedFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const DELAY_MS = 5000;
let lastTime = 0;

text_input.addEventListener('input', function(){
  const current = Date.now();
  if (current - lastTime >= DELAY_MS) {
    // execute code.

    lastTime = current;
  }
});
```

Note that you won't have exactly 5 seconds with that.

You could also try something like that:

```js
const DELAY_MS = 5000;
let inputEventFired = false;

text_input.addEventListener('input', function(){
  inputEventFired = true;
});

setInterval(() => {
  if (inputEventFired) {
    // execute code
  }
}, DELAY_MS);
```